# seems I keep missing the idea of "target" and "rules"

Tags: c++, makefile

tried to make a own makefile using alias
keep getting " make: *** No rule to make target `g++', needed by`release'.  Stop."

```
PROGRAMS  = stl

CPP      = g++                  
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c++98 

DEBUG_FLAGS = -g -DDEBUG -UNDEBUG

RELEASE_FLAGS = -O3 -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG 

TEST_NAME = test$(PROGRAMS).out
DBG_TEST_NAME = test$(PROGRAMS).dbg.out

all:  release debug

release: $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(RELEASE_FLAGS) $(PROGRAMS).cpp -o  $(TEST_NAME)

debug: $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(PROGRAMS).cpp -o $(DBG_TEST_NAME)

clean:
    rm -rvf *.o *.a *.out *dbg.out $(PROGRAMS)
```

Comment: Why don't you try a simpler one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for a target should be on a separate line, indented by a *tab*.

A rule in a makefile is:

```
target: dependencies
    commands-for-rule
```

So in your case, something like e.g.

```
debug: $(PROGRAMS).cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(PROGRAMS).cpp -o $(DBG_TEST_NAME)
```

This makes the `debug` target depend on `$(PROGRAMS).cpp`, so the rule will always be executed if `$(PROGRAMS).cpp` is modified.